# How to add a guest authentication for my Static site on amplify

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've  been building my app's frontend on Amplify(with React). But since its a static site just for the Customers to show some info about our company, We don't require any username and password or email from Viewers. But the thing is to use amplify APIs (REST and Graphql) I need to use Authentication rather than just using it without authentication. Can you suggest me how to create a guest authentication from AWS-Cognito which we can use for REST and Graphql APIs in Amplify without asking any Details from the visitor. If this feels confusing I am willing to explain in detail. Thank you.